# if $x^2$ is irrational, then $x$ is irrational

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-explanation

I know this is a simple proof and you start off with a proof by contradiction and assume $x^2$ is rational, so $x^2$ = $\frac{p^2}{q^2}$. And this is a contradiction because the original assumption was that $x^2$ is irrational. I was just wondering if anybody could further explain how proof by contradiction actually works in this scenario. How does it prove that x is irrational?

Comment: You don't assume $x^2$ is rational. You assume $x$ is  rational (ie. $x = \frac{p}{q}$), and from there prove that $x^2$ is rational. So if $x^2$ is not rational, then $x$ can't be rational.

Comment: You don't do a proof by contradiction, you do a proof by contraposition. Subtle difference, but it's there. To prove $A\implies B$ with contraposition, you assume $\lnot B$ and deduce $\lnot A$ directly. In a proof by contradiction, you assume both $A$ and $\lnot B$, and then you derive a contradiction.

Comment: If you want to do a proof by contradiction, then you don't have the correct negation. It's supposed to be, "Assume $x^2$ is irrational and $x$ is rational."

Comment: @Arthur, so I would have to start the proof by assuming x is rational, but then when I plug in $x^2$ I still get $x^2 = \frac{p^2}{q^2}$. So in the end, will this proof show that there is no possible way for x to be irrational if $x^2$ is irrational (x is rational when $x^2$ is irrational).

Comment: @BlueName321 Your first sentence there is exactly right. You get $x^2 = \frac{p^2}{q^2}$. And what is that? It is a fraction of integers, and thus a rational number. So you have proven there that a rational $x$ must imply a rational $x^2$. By contraposition, that means exactly that an irrational $x^2$ must imply an irrational $x$. Your second sentence is wrong. It is supposed to be "there is no possible way for $x$ to be rational if $x^2$ is irrational". When $x^2$ is irrational, then $x$ must also be irrational.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use the contradiction methode, you assume the negation of the result and use it to prove that the given is not true. i.e. you assume that $x$ is rational and prove that in this case $x^2$ cannot possibly be irrational.
$$x \text{ is rational }$$
$$\Rightarrow\exists a\in \mathbb{Z}, \exists b\in \mathbb{Z}\ast ;x=\frac{a}{b}$$
$$\Rightarrow x^2=\frac{a^2}{b^2}$$
$$\Rightarrow x^2 \text{ is rational}\rightarrow\leftarrow$$

Answer (score 1):

There's no possible use of contradiction here, unless you force it in.

The proof is by contrapositive: the statements

(A) “for every real $x$, if $x^2$ is irrational, then $x$ is irrational”

and

(B) “for every real $x$, if $x$ is rational, then $x^2$ is rational”

are logically equivalent, because “irrational” is the same as ”not rational”.

Any proof by contrapositive can be made to look like a proof by contradiction:

Suppose statement (A) is false. Then there exists a rational $x$ such that $x^2$ is irrational. But this is a contradiction because of statement (B).

This requires proving statement (B) to begin with, of course. But adding the “contradiction argument“ above is a waste of time.